# Why can't I see gnome extensions?

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 with Gnome 3.8.4 and I'm trying to install some gnome extensions.  Now, some of them are installed but don't work or I can't see them.

For example I tried to install "Sensors" and it doesn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: It works! Thanks! But, If i want to install another one?

Comment: Follow their descriptions or Search for a reported same problem on the web, you can also check IRC for minor question: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList OR ask here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to install `lm-sensors`

Type: `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors` in terminal to install it.

After it you can use sensors extension .

I would also suggest to install `gnome-tweak-tool`.